# Vibration / sound priority notifications for a Gmail label that continue until dismissed

Tags: notifications, gmail, accessibility, silent-mode

I know the Gmail app has some per-label notification settings, however I don't see an option for a notification to appear when you have priority notifications only or an option to repeat the notification until it's dismissed.

Gmail Label Notifier used to do this perfectly when it existed. Is there nothing else?

This is essential for being on call. It seems like even if Gmail access was limited, that some program could tap into notifications to kick off the alert.

Same question: http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/gmail-label-notifier-alternative-t3204315